# How to remove box pattern in between the number(string)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
ax.set_yticklabels([str(dslt[0]) + '\t'+str(dssza[0]) + '\t'+str(dslat[0]) + '\t' + str(dsalt[0]).expandtabs())
```

It is printing on the plot as -

```
12[]63[]126[]69
```

instead of tab space.

Comment: can you explain your question more?

Comment: The above code making the adjacent ticks values. In this plot, it is displaying like the above shown. I need to remove the boxes. Basically, I need to string values with tab space.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace `'\t'` with something else? Like a white space `' '` or nothing at all.
I believe boxes are appearing for tab (`'\t'`).
Let me know how do you want your output.

Thank you.

Comment: I need to print like 12 63 126 69 (just a tab space). Thank You

Comment: ' '  white space is worked out for me. But what is wrong with the tab space (\t). Thank You

Comment: What if you manually put 4 white spaces `'    '` instead of `'\t'`.Do those boxes still appear?

Comment: No.  I am getting 12 63 126 69 (depends on the white spaces given). but, if I want to continue like this 3 or 4 time for other values like 1,2,3,4 (above shown for one value). It takes many lines.